# When I Add Dynamic Field jQuery datepicket Is Not Wotking

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jQuery datepicker, when i add dynamic fields, datepicker is not working on dynamically added fields...

Thanks In Advance.

My HTML Date Type Field:

```html
<td><input type="text" name="myDob[]" class="form-control form-control-sm datepicker" placeholder="Date of Birth: "></td>
```

My DatePicker jQuery:

```js
// We don't want the val method to include placehoder value, so removing it here.
var $valFn = $.fn.val;
$.fn.extend({
  val: function() {
    var valCatch = $valFn.apply(this, arguments);
    var placeholder = $(this).attr("placeholder");

    // To check this val is called to set value and the val is for datePicker element 
    if (!arguments.length && this.hasClass('hasDatepicker')) {
      if (valCatch.indexOf(placeholder) != -1) {
        return valCatch.replace(placeholder, "");
      }
    }
    return valCatch;
  }
});

// Insert placeholder as prefix in the value, when user makes a change.
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(arg) {
    $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder") + arg);
  }
});
```

Here is my Dynamic Add Fields jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //group add limit
  var maxGroup = 10;

  //add more fields group
  $(".addMore").click(function() {
    if ($('body').find('.fieldGroup').length < maxGroup) {
      var fieldHTML = '<table class="table table-bordered fieldGroup">' + $(".fieldGroupCopy").html() + '</table>';
      $('body').find('.fieldGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);
    } else {
      alert('Maximum ' + maxGroup + ' groups are allowed.');
    }
  });

  //remove fields group
  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).parents(".fieldGroup").remove();
  });
});
```

Updated Image:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a popular question on stackoverflow... In short if your inputs comes in the DOM after the page has load you had to use event delegation pattern to initialize all the datepickers. A popular trick is to listen when the `document` has `focus`.

```
$( document ).on( "focus", ".datepicker:not(.hasDatepicker)", function() {
   var self = this;
   $(self).datepicker({

     // Your code ....

   });
});
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/50uvmfp6/)

Comment: i've edit the answer: with `:not(.hasDatepicker)` try it

Comment: Your code work well but don't know why my calendar look like this, i mean the left right button on calendar... Look at the updated question i'v attached a pic...

Comment: @Saif Zakir this is not a javascript problem but a css image path problem. Look at your css if the image path is correct. If the answer i've wrote has helped you please rate it

Comment: If you don't mind can you tell me which css `jquery-ui.css`, `bootstrap.css`, `toastr.css`, `toastr-responsive.css` ???

Comment: If you are using [this](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)  the file is `jquery-ui.css`

Comment: Done! Thanks Bro.

Comment: It's a pleasure. I know you’ll do the same for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize a plugin:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    //...
});
```

This only initializes it on the elements matched *at that moment*.  Matching elements added in the future will need to be initialized after they're added.  Note that you'll probably want to more specifically identify the added elements rather than perform a global re-initialization of the plugin on all `.datepicker` elements.

The question then becomes, how can you identify specifically your newly added elements?  For example, are they specifically in a new containing element to which you already have a reference?  If so, you can use that to narrow your selection:

```
$(".datepicker", someContainingElement).datepicker({
    //...
});
```

Or perhaps the newly added elements are given a specific class which is then removed solely for the purpose of identifying them?:

```
$(".newdatepicker").datepicker({
    //...
}).removeClass("newdatepicker");
```

There are a variety of options regarding how you would identify your elements, but the main point is that you need to initialize the plugin on any new elements added to the DOM.

Comment: Bro my eng is too week i updated my question with dynamic add jQuery function could you help me out.. if you don't mind.